# Function introduced by varying upper bound in Lebesgue integral

Tags: real-analysis, integration, measure-theory, proof-verification, lebesgue-measure

I want to show that if $1<p<\infty$, $f\in L_p(]0,\infty[)$ and $G(x):=\frac{1}{x}\int \chi_{]0,x[}f\, d\lambda$ it is $G\in L_p(]0,\infty[)$ and $\Vert G\Vert_p\leq\frac{p}{p-1}\Vert f\Vert_p$. I was told to first assume continuity and compact support for $f$ and show it is in $C^1(]0,\infty[)\cap L_p(]0,\infty[)$.

So, under these assumptions, I thought: As $f$ is bounded it is integrable on $]0,x[$. As it is regulated on $]0,x[$ it is absolutely integrable, so $G$ is defined and $G(x)$ is equal to the improper integral $\int_0^x f\, dx$. So, continuity of $G$ is obvious, continuous differentiability follows from the fundamental theorem of calculus and the identity of the derivative: $G'(x)=-\frac{1}{x^2}G(x)+\frac{1}{x}f(x)$. As it is $\vert G\vert^p\leq \frac{1}{x^p}\lambda(K)^p\Vert f\Vert_\infty^p$ and $p>1$ it is $G\in L_p(]0,\infty[)$.

Is this ok so far? Now how do I show the inequality? Where do I use the compact support and how can I show the general statement? (I know $C_c$ is dense in $L_p$). Any hints?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you had a small mistake in your calculation of $G'(x)$, as you'll see. But for now, suppose $f \in C_c^1(\mathbb{R})$. So $G(x) = \displaystyle \frac1x \int_0^x f(t) \ dt$. Now

$$\int_0^\infty G(x)^p \ dx = xG(x)^p\biggm|_0^\infty - p\int_0^\infty xG'(x)G(x)^{p-1}\ dx$$
$$= - p\int_0^\infty xG'(x)G(x)^{p-1}\ dx.$$

This follows because $G(x) \to 0$ as $x \to \infty$, since $f$ is compactly supported. Now 
$$G'(x) = \frac{-1}{x^2}\int_0^xf(t) \ dt +\frac{f(x)}{x} =\frac{-G(x) + f(x)}{x}.$$

Plugging this in to our result above, we get

$$\int_0^\infty G(x)^p \ dx = -p\int_0^\infty -G(x)^p +G(x)^{p-1}f(x) \ dx$$
hence
$$(1-p)\int_0^\infty G(x)^p \ dx = -p \int_0^\infty G(x)^{p-1}f(x) \ dx$$
so 
$$\int_0^\infty G(x)^p \ dx \le \frac{p}{p-1}\int_0^\infty G(x)^{p-1}f(x) \ dx.$$
Now applying Holder's inequality we get
$$\|G\|_p^p \le \frac{p}{p-1}\|G\|_p^{p/q} \|f\|_p$$
from which it follows 
$$\|G\|_p \le \frac{p}{p-1}\|f\|_p.$$

Comment: Thanks alot, that did help. Do we need to assume positive values for $f$ for your proof to work? And, to show that statement for any $f$ in $L_p$, do you have a hint on how to proceed?

Comment: Oh, no you shouldn't need positive $f$. You can stick absolute values in my proof and the inequalities should work in your favor (i.e., $\int f \le \int |f|$). As for the general $L^p$, use density of $C^1_c$.

Comment: Ok, but I'd need to work with $G^*(x):=\frac{1}{X}\int_0^x \vert f(x)\vert\, dx$ and then compare? In order to use the differentiability in the first step... So, does the convergence of a sequence $(f_j)$ of compact support in $L_p$ imply the convergence of the $G_j$ in $L_p$? Thanks again!